# What libs should I include when compiling with mingw?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, mingw, mapi

I'm trying to compile the [MAPI example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171096) for windows, using MinGW compiler (on linux).

I tried straightforward approach:

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-g++ swpmain.h swpmain.cpp swap.h swap.cpp
//
// bunch of warnings here...
//
/tmp/ccggw42y.o:swap.cpp:(.text+0x2f9): undefined reference to `_MAPIInitialize@4'
/tmp/ccggw42y.o:swap.cpp:(.text+0x31c): undefined reference to `_MAPIAllocateBuffer@8'
/tmp/ccggw42y.o:swap.cpp:(.text+0x350): undefined reference to `_MAPIUninitialize@0'
/tmp/ccggw42y.o:swap.cpp:(.text+0x41a): undefined reference to `_MAPIAllocateBuffer@8'
/tmp/ccggw42y.o:swap.cpp:(.text+0x445): undefined reference to `_MAPIAllocateBuffer@8'
/tmp/ccggw42y.o:swap.cpp:(.text+0x65f): undefined reference to `_MAPIAllocateBuffer@8'
/tmp/ccggw42y.o:swap.cpp:(.text+0xf5b): undefined reference to `_MAPIFreeBuffer@4'
/tmp/ccggw42y.o:swap.cpp:(.text+0xf6c): undefined reference to `_MAPIFreeBuffer@4'
/tmp/ccggw42y.o:swap.cpp:(.text+0x1782): undefined reference to `_MAPIFreeBuffer@4'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`ld` error hints that I forgot to include some library - but I can't figure out which one. I tried searching files in usr/, but I only found `mapi.h` and `mapix.h` headers - no libraries.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How about `libmapi32.a`? There's also a `libdwmapi.a`. Try it and see.

Comment: @thokra - Yes, that did it!

Comment: @thokra - I also needed `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` options, to make it bundle the libs into executable

Comment: Huh? Why would that be necessary? Really strange...

Comment: @thokra - They are not present on the windows machine I use for testing (it's a barebones win xp install). Thus, if I didn't use those options, it refused to start.